# How to set a variable in CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following command to set my own IP in a variable :

```
    for /F %I in ('curl http://ipecho.net/plain') do set ip=%I
```

When I open cmd and write (or paste) the command manually, it's working properly. The variable %ip% is set and the command

```
    echo %ip%
```

returns my IP address.

However if I put this command in a cmd file and run the cmd file, I'm getting the error :

```
    //ipecho.net/plain') was unexpected.
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like it says in the help (for /?)

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
> of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
> from %I.

So, replace each %I by %%I.

Annoying, but there it is.